# Can Vuforia track spatial location when using targetless device tracking?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, google-project-tango

I am trying to wrap my head around Vuforia's capabilities. I want to make an app which lets me place a 3D object into a camera view and have that 3D object stick to the world. I've been learning how to use Vuforia in Unity3D, and Vuforia seems to be slightly capable of this, but is severely limited by its craving for "Targets". It doesn't seem to be able to do much if I don't give it some sort of target.

One workaround I've found is to set the `ARCamera`'s `World Center Mode` to `DEVICE_TRACKING`. This seems to let me place a 3D object into the world (in Unity) and have this object overlay into the camera feed, almost making it seem like it's anhcored to the real world. This doesn't work perfectly though: it tracks properly when I angle the device up/down/left/right (rotation), but it does *not* seem to track the device's *translational* motion; that is, when I move the device forward/back/left/right, the overlaid object doesn't get closer/farther nor does it rotate as I move around it.

Is it possible to get this sort of tracking out of Vuforia, **or am I better off switching to something like Google Tango?**

Answer (score 1):

The [difficulty](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/unity-extension-technical-discussion/what-world-center-mode) with setting World Center Mode to CAMERA in Vuforia is that apparently 3D objects rotate around the camera based on its accelerometer/gyroscope changes. This doesn't allow for objects to be anchored to the environment. Instead they follow with the camera.

[Kudan](https://www.kudan.eu/) is a good markerless tracking option.

Comment: Thanks, I've started to look into kudan because of your answer to my other post

Comment: You're fast, it wasn't that long ago!

Comment: Vuforia doesn't yet handle markerless scenes with many moving things  in them well. I lean toward Vuforia for that reason.